# Create DVD-Video Menu's with ff-mpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to create a DVD-Video Menu with ff-mpeg only ?

I may be misunderstanding but I don't think that ff-mpeg alone is capable of creating a dvd menu.

I've found some examples using ff-mpeg and various other tools but nothing solely ff-mpeg. The other tools are all linux and I'm stuck in windows.

If someone would clear that up for me that would be great. Also if you know of a library for creating dvd menus or a command line utility would also help.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg cannot do that. Try [DVDAuthor](http://dvdauthor.sourceforge.net/) instead. [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvdauthor/files/dvdauthor/0.6.9/) are (quite old) precompiled binaries for windows.